# Creating polygons based on point layer attribute values using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have point layer that has attributes about object's physical dimensions ("width" and "length"), I would like to create rectangular polygon layer around these points (with them being centroids).

Is there some QGIS algorithm that can be applied?

Comment: you can do this by using QGIS expressions together with the geometry by expression algorithm.
If you publish a mini-dataset I can create an example for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native tool [`rectangles, ovals, diamonds`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds) does exactly what you're looking for. Hand it your point layer, set the attributes as data-defined override, maybe add a rotation, and the tool hands you your rectangles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Marking this, as accepted answer.